# Bootstrap modal, and SEO

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, seo, popover

I'm using bootstrap to show content in modal popover, using links like:

```
<a href="/content/modal/23797" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contentModal" title="Some content">View Content</a></pre>
```

I'm doing this for UX, so that user doesn't need to leave the page they are on to see the content.  However, I do want Google to index the actual content page, which is not the modal version.  The URL for the actual content is "/content/23797", which displays in a regular full page of the site.

The problem is that the modal popup should only reference the modal version, but I want Google to crawl the full version, since that page actually exists and should be indexed.

Any idea how to make the modal popover access the modal content, but still allow for Google to see the actual content page URL in the href?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
(1) Are your page dynamically generated. This can be a problem since you don't have content of the page yet and will only generate it at the time of user request and this i dont know how to make google crawl its popover version of pages.

(2) If your pages are all known ahead while not build a sitemap and upload it to google webmaster and this will guide web crawlers like Googlebot that gives them a list of web pages on your site.

visit google webmaster [Here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/)
Signup and create you sitemap guide is everywhere on how to do sitemap. Then upload it .....

They will discover and index your pages if they exits in your site.

Comment: They are all dynamic, and I need them to be crawled organically, via href.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the link to the full page (**/content/23797**) and code in JS to change the URL for the modal when the user clicks that link.